# using php htmlentities to convert quotes to html entities for XML output

Tags: php

I have a problem when creating some XML.
I am querying a MySQL database to create the XML.

The XML is being created fine normally.
When I add text to the "summary" field with a single quote in it i get a compile error - with no details.

I have added htmlentities() function to the code to get round this but it doesn't help.

When I remove the content of the field with the single quote in it the XML renders fine, so I know the problem lies in the content of the field. [Extra comment: If i just take out the single quote from the text the XML compiles properly]

Below is the code I am using. Any tips would be gratefully received.
The "summary" field is the field that is causing the error.

```
    <?php  

require("../xxxxxxx.php"); 

// Start XML file, create parent node

$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node); 

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server

$connection=mysql_connect ($viewer_host, $viewer_user, $viewer_pass);
if (!$connection) {  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());} 

// Set the active MySQL database

$db_selected = mysql_select_db($viewer_db, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db: ');//. mysql_error()
} 

// Select all the rows in the markers table

$query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {  
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
} 

header("Content-type: text/xml"); 

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each

while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){  
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE  
  $node = $dom->createElement("marker");  
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
  $newnode->setAttribute("id",$row['id']); 
  $newnode->setAttribute("name",htmlentities($row['name']));
  $newnode->setAttribute("summary", htmlentities($row['summary']));
  $newnode->setAttribute("address", htmlentities($row['address']));
  $newnode->setAttribute("region", htmlentities($row['region'])); 
  $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);  
  $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);  
  $newnode->setAttribute("type", $row['type']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("artform", htmlentities($row['artform']));
} 

echo $dom->saveXML();

?>
```

Comment: have you tried replacing the character of " with an html encoded &quot; ?

Comment: @durbnpoisn I thought that was what the htmlentities function was supposed to do? eg, change stuff like single quotes to their 'entity' versions

Comment: @durbnpoisn Just tried replacing the content in the DB with &quot; and it worked. However the content in the DB is from the users and contains normal quotes, so i need to convert it on the fly. normally i would convert when putting in the database but this is coming from a spreadsheet not the web user interface.

Comment: Hmm, yes.  It is.  I was just wondering if you had tried it manually, just to make sure it was really capturing the correct character.

Comment: @durbnpoisn, any ideas what this might mean? the conversion is not being done i guess???

Comment: You say this is coming from a spreadsheet.  Excel sometimes makes funny assumptions on characters because it thinks they are part of a formula.  Can you verify that the data in the sheet is not something like "=b6" which would actually give you the value of B6?